# how to individualize each post? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebox

On each user profile (localhost:3000/users/username), there's a listing of posts that the user has made. I implemented facebox which is a jQuery-based lightbox to display images when clicked on. This is the code that I'm using for that:

```
<a href=<%= post.image_url %> rel="facebox"><%= image_tag post.image_url(:thumb).to_s %></a>
```

**The problem is that, if a user has made 5 posts, the same image is repeated 5 times when clicked on to display in facebox.**

This is my show.html.erb where I render in @posts

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
       <br>
  </aside>
 <br>


  <div class="span10">
    <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
    <% if @user.posts.empty? %>
<h3>Browse</h3>
<% end %>
    <% if @user.posts.any? %>
      <ol class="posts">
        <%= render @posts %>

      </ol>

      <%= will_paginate @posts %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's the _post.html.erb

```
<script src="/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/src/facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/src/facebox.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script language="javascript">

 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox() 
}) 

</script>


    <li>
      <span class="content"><%= simple_format(post.content) %></span>
      <% if post.image.present? %>
      <a href=<%= post.image_url %> rel="facebox"><%= image_tag post.image_url(:thumb).to_s %></a>
      <br>
      <% else %>
      <% end %>
      <span class="timestamp">
        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago.
      </span>
</li>
```

Comment: There's no error, but when I click on the image to show it in the popup (facebox script), the same image is repeated that correlates to how many posts that a user has. So if a user has 11 posts, the image when clicked on is repeated 11 times in one popup

Comment: Can you post the javascript code you have written that initializes facebox? I tried creating a sample project to reproduce this, but I couldn't reproduce it, so maybe a jsFiddle that demonstrates this would help too.

Comment: sure, I posted up the script portion of the _post.html.erb in the updated above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript in `_post.html.erb` is included and executed once for each post. Therefore, if the user has five posts, you are initializing facebox five times.  Move the script tags out of the partial. Instead, place them in `show.html.erb` so that they will only execute once for the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

I think facebox groups the images automatically because the all have the same "rel" attribute.

Try something like this:

```
<%= link_to post.image_url, :rel => "facebox-#{post.id}" do %>
  <%= image_tag post.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm unfortunately getting the same issue. To explain further, if I have 2 different image postings on localhost:3000/users/username and when I click on one of them, the same image is repeated. The image that is displayed is correct but it is repeated depending on how many posts that a user has.

Comment: Investigate the generated HTML source. Although I don't know facebox well, this really sounds like it tries to group "different" images (all images with the exact same rel-attribute) to be displayed at once.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still not lucky, try to remove the rel attribute and call facebox based on a class name:

```
<%= link_to post.image_url, :class => "facebox" do %>
  <%= image_tag post.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
<% end %>
```

And the javascript:

```
$('a.facebox').facebox()
```